# Extjs TreePanel: How can I hide nodes by class or attribute?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a tree with nodes that contain tasks.

Completed tasks have attribute status: 100 and class cls: "done".

I would like to make a button for hiding completed tasks.

**What function will hide nodes in a tree by their id or class?**

```
{"id":"45",
"description":"Pay bills",
"status":"100",
"cls":"done",
"uiProvider":"col",
"leaf":true}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try walking the tree starting at the root and testing for the attribute(s) you want. If you get a hit, hide the node:

```
tree.getRootNode().cascade(function() { // descends into child nodes
    if(this.attributes['status'] == 100) { // test this node
        this.getUI().hide() // hide this node
    }
})
```

You actually asked about testing by the class `"done"`. In that case just test if `this.attributes['cls'] == 'done'` instead. I prefer checking `"status"` than `"cls"` as the latter can be space-separated and messy.

Comment: Didn't work for me in Ext JS 4.1.3. Such an easy requirement, and Ext JS doesn't have it. That's why I hate Ext JS.

Answer (score 1):

For ExtJS 6, for example, when read config is false, hide the node:

```
hideItemsReadFalse: function () {
    var me = this,
        items = me.getReferences().treelistRef.itemMap;


    for(var i in items){
        if(items[i].config.node.data.read == false){
            items[i].destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Root:

```
{
    "text": "root",
    "children": [
        {
            "text": "Atualização",
            "iconCls": "x-fa fa-list",
            "children": [
                {
                    "leaf":true,
                    "text": "Empresas",
                    "module": "empresas",
                    "iconCls": "x-fa fa-building",
                    "read": false
                },
                {
                    "leaf":true,
                    "text": "Produtos",
                    "module": "produtos",
                    "iconCls": "x-fa fa-cubes",
                    "read": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```